# I'm trying to create a spfx environment, i ran command "npm i -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint" and i returned with error "code EEXIST"

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, gulp, spfx, yo

my node version is 10.13.0, i'm using this version because of a specific project dependency and i'm using my office laptop,
I'm also having
+-- gulp@4.0.2
+-- typescript@4.9.5
`-- yo@4.3.1

i want to install "npm i -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint" but i'm getting error "code EEXIST"

I'm new to this so don't have much knowledge what is this and i'm working on this for 2 days still not able to fix it.

```
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.1.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated read-package-tree@5.1.6: The functionality that this package provided is now in @npmcli/arborist
npm WARN deprecated readdir-scoped-modules@1.1.0: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint\node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint\node_modules\@rushstack\typings-generator\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN yeoman-generator@5.6.1 requires a peer of yeoman-environment@^3.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @rushstack/webpack4-module-minifier-plugin@0.9.31 requires a peer of @types/webpack@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @rushstack/webpack4-module-minifier-plugin@0.9.31 requires a peer of @types/webpack-sources@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN node-fetch@2.6.7 requires a peer of encoding@^0.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @rushstack/webpack4-localization-plugin@0.15.25 requires a peer of @types/webpack@^4.39.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @rushstack/set-webpack-public-path-plugin@3.3.69 requires a peer of @types/webpack@^4.39.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @rushstack/set-webpack-public-path-plugin@3.3.69 requires a peer of webpack@^5.35.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @microsoft/loader-load-themed-styles@1.9.174 requires a peer of @types/webpack@^4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN node-fetch@2.6.9 requires a peer of encoding@^0.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN node-fetch@2.6.7 requires a peer of encoding@^0.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @rushstack/webpack-plugin-utilities@0.1.36 requires a peer of @types/webpack@^4.39.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @rushstack/webpack-plugin-utilities@0.1.36 requires a peer of webpack@^5.35.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@8.12.0 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@8.12.0 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@>=5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-formats@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path C:\Users\AryanSharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint\node_modules\.bin\browserslist.cmd
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\AryanSharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint\node_modules\.bin\browserslist.cmd: is outside C:\Users\AryanSharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint\node_modules\browserslist and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\AryanSharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint\node_modules\.bin\browserslist.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AryanSharma\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-02T09_55_50_116Z-debug.log
```

I want to create a new webpart but so many errors

Answer (score 0):

as this error suggests: **npm ERR! Move it away, and try again**. Please Check whether you have installed the package in your environment, and then try to remove and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the yeoman template you are trying to install is not compatible with NodeJs v10.13.1.  Use the following command instead

```
npm i -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.12.1
```

The full list of SPFx compatibility can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility

From that list, you can see that SPFx v1.12.1 is the last version that supported NodeJs v10.x

Also, you should remove gulp from the global space and replace it with gulp-cli by running the following commands

```
npm uninstall - gulp
npm i -g gulp-cli
```

Having typescript installed is also unneeded, so that can be uninstalled.
Lastly, you can always ignore the WARN messages.

Good luck!

Good luck!Don

---

If my answer helps solve or resolve your issue, please consider clicking  **Mark as Best Response** & **Like**. This will help others to find the correct solution easily. It also closes the item. If the post was useful in other ways, please consider giving it a **Like**.